# How can I mass-update elements in an array using Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a database with accounts. I need to update the fields to different ones in each account.
The account looks something like this:

```
const obj = {
  id: 492,
  type: 'sel',
  username: 'username@outlook.com',
  password: 'password',
  proxy: {
    ip: 'some_ip',
    type: 'http',
    port: '222',
    datacenter: null,
    targeting: 'country',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'ffsfs',
    provider: 'noname'
  },
}
```

I can update these fields for one account in this way:

```
db.Account.findById(492)
.then((a) => {
     let countryCode = a.country.toUpperCase();
     let country = getName(countryCode).replace(/\s/g, '');
     let sessionId = randomstring.generate({
       charset: 'alphanumeric',
       length: 6
     });
     const proxyPassword = `${country}_ses-${sessionId}`;
     
     let newProxy = Object.assign({}, a.proxy);

     newProxy.provider = 'provider';
     newProxy.password = proxyPassword;
     newProxy.username = 'username';
     newProxy.port = '121212';
     newProxy.ip = 'proxy.ip';

     return a.update({
       proxy: newProxy
     });
 }).catch((e) => {
     console.log(e);
   })
```

But when I try to do the same with an array an error appears in the console:

TypeError: a.update is not a function

I'm trying to do it this way:

```
db.Account.findAll({
    where: { 
      id: [492, 572, 2]
    },  raw: true 
  })
    .then((accounts) => {
      accounts.forEach((a) => {
        let countryCode = a.country.toUpperCase();
        let country = getName(countryCode).replace(/\s/g, '');
        let sessionId = randomstring.generate({
          charset: 'alphanumeric',
          length: 6
        });
        const proxyPassword = `${country}_ses-${sessionId}`;
        
        let newProxy = Object.assign({}, a.proxy);

        newProxy.provider = 'provider';
        newProxy.password = proxyPassword;
        newProxy.username = 'username';
        newProxy.port = '121212';
        newProxy.ip = 'proxy.ip';

        return a.update({
          proxy: newProxy
        });
 }).catch((e) => {
     console.log(e);
   })
```

Why is this happening? Any help please!

Update.
I tried doing this and it seems to work:

```
 db.Account.findAll({
    where: { 
      id: [492, 572, 2]
    },  raw: true 
  })
    .then((accounts) => {
      let updates = accounts.map((a) => {
        let countryCode = a.country.toUpperCase();
        let country = getName(countryCode).replace(/\s/g, '');
        let sessionId = randomstring.generate({
          charset: 'alphanumeric',
          length: 6
        });
        const proxyPassword = `${country}_ses-${sessionId}`;
        
        let newProxy = Object.assign({}, a.proxy);

        newProxy.provider = 'provider';
        newProxy.password = proxyPassword;
        newProxy.username = 'username';
        newProxy.port = '121212';
        newProxy.ip = 'proxy.ip';

        db.Account.findById(a.id)
        .then((item) => {
          item.update({
            proxy: newProxy
          });
        })
      })
    Promise.all(updates)
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call an asynchronous function in a synchronous loop, and even though it looks like the model is not parsed, and the last thing there is a workaround in Sequelize to bulk update data, so there is no need to execute update multiple times.

```
db.Account
  .findAll({
    where: {
      id: [492, 572, 2]
    },
    raw: true
  })
  .then((accounts) => {
    const data = accounts.map((a) => {
      let countryCode = a.country.toUpperCase();
      let newProxy = Object.assign({}, a.proxy);
      newProxy.provider = 'provider';
      a.countryCode = countryCode;
      a.proxy = newProxy;
      // change all data then return the new account and it must include the id attribute
      return a;
    });

    return db.Account.bulkCreate(data, { updateOnDuplicate: ['id'] });
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

For references:

- [Asynchronous JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous)
- [Sequelize workaround](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4501#issuecomment-466983377)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer it became clearer to me! But, unfortunately, my database is postgres of the old version. And I have no way to update it. Please see my response update. Is this method acceptable?

Comment: Sequelize `bulkCreate` will execute multiple queries to update your records, so it will exactly do the same thing you want but with one line of code, it is strongly recommended to leverage the used ORM methods instead of writing your own. Did you get any errors when trying to use it?

Comment: No errors were made. It's just that the bulkCreate method is not supported by my version of sequelize and postgres. In any case, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome, please mark the answer as correct if it did help.